# no S3 sleep mode on HP x360 spectre

Tags: uefi, suspend, bios

I have a dual boot setup at HP Spectre x360 Tablet 13" ap0xxx
(BIOS F.27/16Gb RAM/512Gb SSD/model 2018)
Win10/Linux (Fedora 30 and Kubuntu 19.04)

Problem:
There is no S3 mode available in either of Linux distro.
Have tried stock kernels as well as latest for ubuntu 5.1.4-050104-generic

```
dmesg | grep ACPI | grep supports
[    0.371691] ACPI: (supports S0 S4 S5)

cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
[s2idle]
```

Questions: 
Is it Linux kernel issue or BIOS/UEFI?
Is there a way to solve it, if HP keeps silence?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like S3 is not supported on this machine, but there's hope as acpi is poorly implemented for linux, only hp must implement proper acpi tables...I've already written to HP to request they fix this issue. Perhaps they would act if we are numerous enough asking for it.
Also deep sleep works from windows side.
I'm on bios F28 and the issue is not solved

Comment: I agree as more requests we send as more chances that HP will fix BIOS. What e-mail is good to contact HP?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any workaround